# How to communicate between ractive components?

Tags: components, ractivejs

I had a problem where I wanted to call functions in different ractI've component.
E.g I have 2 ractive components A and B, I wanted to call `A.xyz()` fintion from another ractive component B.

Comment: What is the relationship between the components in the view hierarchy? Are they in an ancestor/descendent relationship? Or are they siblings?

Comment: There is no relation at all. Component A and B are in different hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

We can use global Ractive instance for that.
From component B fire event on global Ractive instance.

```
Ractive.default.fire('call.componentA.event')
```

Catch this event on component B

```
Ractive.default.on('call.componentA.event', function (){
//Do your stuff here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to fire the message on `Ractive` root instead

**component A.js**

```
export default Ractive.extend({

  template,

  oninit () {
    ...
    var obj = {// some data to be sent to component B};

    this.root.fire('eventType', obj);
  }

});
```

and in component B **"receive"** it

**componentB.js**

```
export default Ractive.extend({

  template, // template for 


  oninit () {

    this.root.on('eventType', ( obj ) => {
         // ...do something with the object
    });
  }

});
```